# manually editing color of confidence intervals and mean across ggplot2 facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can choose the color of my confidence intervals in ggplot, but it fails when I try to plot these intervals in different facets.

This works as expected

```
df=data.frame(Effectsize=seq(from=1, to=20,   by=1),percentile=as.factor(rep(c("10th","50th"), 10)),   name=as.factor(rep(c("Group1","Group2","Group2","Group1","Group1"), 4)))


ggplot(df, aes(y=Effectsize, x=percentile))+xlab("")+ylab("Effect size (Slope/SD)")+
geom_boxplot(fill="transparent", colour="transparent")+
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", colour=c("turquoise", "orange"))+
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", colour=c("turquoise", "orange"))
```

[image]

But when i try to plot that in facets, it doesn't plot the two ribbons with their colors per facet.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=Effectsize, x=percentile))+xlab("")+ylab("Effect size (Slope/SD)")+
geom_boxplot(fill="transparent", colour="transparent")+
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", colour=c("turquoise", "orange"))+
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", colour=c("turquoise", "orange"))+
facet_grid(. ~ name)+theme(legend.position = "none")
```

and comes the error:
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): colour
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Adding

```
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("turquoise", "orange")) +
```

did not help either.

What could be the work around?

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're looking for. The colors are correct in both.

Comment: I would expect three ribbons in each facet

Comment: The problem, Agus, is that in the dataset you created all observations from "Group1" have a percentile value of "10th", all from "Group2" a "50th", and all of Group3 a "90th". 
Thus, when you facet by `name`, each facet has only obvservation from one horizontal category.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the dummy dataset, now it reproduces de problem more satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

`colour=c("turquoise", "orange")`

to

`colour=c("turquoise", "orange", "turquoise", "orange")`

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=Effectsize, x=percentile))+xlab("")+ylab("Effect size (Slope/SD)")+
  geom_boxplot(fill="transparent", colour="transparent")+
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", colour=c("turquoise", "orange", "turquoise", "orange"))+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", colour=c("turquoise", "orange", "turquoise", "orange"))+
  facet_grid(. ~ name)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]